# How can i create a Date Object without time when using YYYY-MM-DD in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I am having trouble to create a Date only Date Object when using the 'YYYY-MM-DD' input

When i use the following Code to create a new Date object

```
let date1 = new Date('2022-01-06')
let date2 = new Date('01/06/2022')
```

I get the following results

```
date1 = Wed Jan 05 2022 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
date2 = Thu Jan 06 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

So its the same Input to create a new Date Object but i get different times. As i am storing my data in a json doc store its in the 2022-01-06 format and i need to get a date object back that has no Time just like Date2

Comment: [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) instantiates dates in your timezone. Plus there is a lot of solid integration with Angular. Down side is that it is somewhat extra in package size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
let date1 = new Date('2022-01-06').toLocaleDateString("en-US")
```

it will give you output like this :

**'1/6/2022'**

**and here is another example :**

```
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var today  = new Date();
```

> console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US")); // 9/17/2016
> console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)); // Saturday,
> September 17, 2016

I took reference from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34015511/11004482)

And if you want to use any third party library there are so many which can help you with that [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) I'm attaching one

Example :

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
```

it will return :

> Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM

**List of third party libraries**

1. Date-fns
2. Moment
3. Day JS

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use DatePipe to convert date in this format 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
...
constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe){}
...
public date:Date;
myMethod(){
 this.date=new Date();
 let LatestDate =this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

and just add Datepipe in 'providers' array of app.module.ts.